# How to modify unity game data

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

How can i modify the timer of this unity game with gg.? every 10 seconds equals 1 point i want to alter the points without actually playing [click to see game image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcFXb.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you with your question, but are these bubbles images yours or you downloaded it from an open source?

Comment: We'd likely need a code sample of what you are trying to do to be able to help you.  Also I think Unity runs C#, not Java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.